# Android: MapOverlay - Current location

Tags: android, overlay

I am currently creating an Android application, that shows the user its current location on Google Maps. I currently have it working so brings up the location, zoomed in.

However, I want the location to be pin-pointed. I have attempted to try and follow the HelloMapView tutorial, but have been having difficulty. How do I modify what the tutorial is saying, to make the Overlay, show the current location?

Also, I have been getting an error, with the getDrawable part of the following:

```
Drawable drawable = ((Object) this.getResources()).getDrawable(R.drawable.androidmarker);
ItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new ItemizedOverlay(drawable, this);

Also, whereabouts do I paste this:
itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
```

Thank you.